# "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" em .append JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou recebendo "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" que acusa a linha do ultimo parentese fechado, isso dentro do callback de um post jquery. Tentei fechar de todas formas possíveis, e mesmo assim recebo o erro. Não entendo como tem que ser fechado esses parenteses.

```
$("#exchangers tbody").append(
    $("<tr class='tr_row' id='tr_" + elPosition + "'>").css({cursor:'pointer'}).append(
        $("<td id='td_" + elPosition + "'>").append($("<i id='io" + elPosition + "' onmousedown='shc(" + elPosition + ")' onclick='stopBubbling(event)' onmouseover=\"show_info(" + elPosition + ", '" + el.nome + "', '" + el.https + "', '" + el.moeda_from + "', '" + el.moeda_to + "', '" + el.idade + "', '" + el.url_redirect + "', '" + el.wmid + "', '" + el.pais_nome + "', '" + el.rank_from + "', '" + el.rank_to + "', '" + el.amount + "')\" onmouseout='shd(" + elPosition + ")'>").addClass('fa fa-info-circle io').html("")),
        $("<td>").html('<a class="a_row" href="' + URL_SITE + '/click/' + el.exchange_rates + '.html" target="_blank">' + el.nome + '</a>'),
        $("<td>").html(el.in + " " + el.from),
        $("<td>").html(el.out + " " + el.to),
        $("<td>").html(el.amount + " " + el.to),
        $("<td class='a_comment text-center'>").append(
            '<a class="a_row" style="width: 90px !important;" href="' + URL_SITE + '/exchangers/' + el.link_permanente + '.html">',
            $('<span>').append(
                $('<span>').addClass('text-danger').html(parseInt(el.reviews[0]["negativo"])),
                "/",
                $('<span>').addClass('text-success').html(parseInt(el.reviews[0]["positivo"]) + parseInt(el.reviews[0]["comentario"]) + parseInt(el.reviews[0]["negativo"])),
            ),
            '</a>'
        )
    );
```

Comentando o código por partes, percebi que o erro vem daqui:

```
$("<tr class='tr_row' id='tr_" + elPosition + "'>").css({cursor:'pointer'}).append(
     $("<td id='td_" + elPosition + "'>").append($("<i id='io" + elPosition + "' onmousedown='shc(" + elPosition + ")' onclick='stopBubbling(event)' onmouseover=\"show_info(" + elPosition + ", '" + el.nome + "', '" + el.https + "', '" + el.moeda_from + "', '" + el.moeda_to + "', '" + el.idade + "', '" + el.url_redirect + "', '" + el.wmid + "', '" + el.pais_nome + "', '" + el.rank_from + "', '" + el.rank_to + "', '" + el.amount + "')\" onmouseout='shd(" + elPosition + ")'>").addClass('fa fa-info-circle io').html(""))
```

Estou esquecendo de escapar algo?

Comment: Veja bem, sua pergunta inicial possuía um erro que foi apontado na resposta... ao alterar a sua resposta agora sem o erro, irá tornar a resposta inválida. Tudo bem que o problema pode até não ser exatamente somente o caso do parênteses, mas não altere a pergunta inutilizando respostas dadas. O que se deve fazer é editar a pergunta e adicionar novas informações.

Comment: Removi a resposta para poder entender melhor. O código parece estar correto, mas mesmo assim está dando erro?

Comment: Parece ser algo com as *aspas*, em uns lugares você usa aspa dupla pro Javascript e aspa única pro html dinâmico, depois você faz o oposto em outro lugar.
Tente seguir um padrão único, também ao que me lembro.
Tipo este:
`onclick='stopBubbling(event)' onmouseover=\"show_info(" + elPosition`

No onclick você usou aspa única e no onmouseover aspa dupla com barra invertida pra funcionar, mas em algum ponto aí você escreveu de modo que confundiu o javascript.

Comment: O que está me parecendo é que algum texto nas variáveis está vindo com aspas e está "quebrando" o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PerduGames,
O que fiz no seu código:

- Adicionei um parênteses no final antes do ';' para fechar a primeira
  função append do jquery;
- Alterei as aspas duplas \" na chamada de onmouseover para apóstrofo ' (ou aspa simples);
- Retirei uma virgula a mais no último append.

Executou normalmente aqui.

```js
var elPosition = 1;
var URL_SITE = 'http:www.com';

var el = {
  nome: 'Cleyton',  https: 'Sim', moeda_from: 'USD', moeda_to: 'BRL', idade: 100, url_redirect: 'Pagamento', wmid: 1, pais_nome: 'For for way', rank_from: 1, rank_to: 2, amount: 1.00, in: 'entrada', out: 'saida', from: 'Joaquim', to: 'Pedro', reviews:[{negativo: 2,positivo: 5,comentario: 2}]
};



$("#exchangers tbody").append(
    $("<tr class='tr_row' id='tr_" + elPosition + "'>")
        .css({cursor:'pointer'})
        .append(
            $("<td id='td_" + elPosition + "'>")
                .append(
                    $("<i id='io" + elPosition + "' onmousedown='shc(" + elPosition + ")' onclick='stopBubbling(event)' onmouseover='show_info(" + elPosition + ", '" + el.nome + "', '" + el.https + "', '" + el.moeda_from + "', '" + el.moeda_to + "', '" + el.idade + "', '" + el.url_redirect + "', '" + el.wmid + "', '" + el.pais_nome + "', '" + el.rank_from + "', '" + el.rank_to + "', '" + el.amount + "') onmouseout='shd(" + elPosition + ")'>")
                    .addClass('fa fa-info-circle io')
                    .html("")
                ),
            $("<td>").html('<a class="a_row" href="' + URL_SITE + '/click/' + el.exchange_rates + '.html" target="_blank">' + el.nome + '</a>'),
            $("<td>").html(el.in + " " + el.from),
            $("<td>").html(el.out + " " + el.to),
            $("<td>").html(el.amount + " " + el.to),
            $("<td class='a_comment text-center'>").append(
                '<a class="a_row" style="width: 90px !important;" href="' + URL_SITE + '/exchangers/' + el.link_permanente + '.html">',
                $('<span>').append(
                    $('<span>').addClass('text-danger').html(parseInt(el.reviews[0]["negativo"])),
                    "/",
                    $('<span>').addClass('text-success').html(parseInt(el.reviews[0]["positivo"]) + parseInt(el.reviews[0]["comentario"]) + parseInt(el.reviews[0]["negativo"]))
                ),
                '</a>'
            )
        )
    );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id='exchangers'>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```